# Evaluate conditional expectation $E[e^X | Y=1]$

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Given $X,Y \sim N(0,1)$, X,Y follows a joint normal distribution and $corr(X,Y) = \frac{1}{2}$.

Evaluate $E[e^X|Y=1]$.

I'm not sure where to start on this one. I did a change of variable $Z = e^X$ and use the definition of conditional expectaion: $E[Z|Y=1] = \sum_{z} zp_{Z|Y}(z|y)$ but it isn't helpful.

Comment: this question is under specified, since you do not know the full joint distribution of X and Y

Comment: X,Y follow a joint normal distribution.

Comment: This is the MGF of a normal distribution evaluated at $1$, since $X$ given $Y$ is univariate normal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the law of a Gaussian vector of mean zero is determined by its covariance matrix,
you can write $X=Y/2+t Z$ where $Y,Z$ are i.i.d. $N(0,1)$ variables and $t=\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}$ (In the sense that this pair $(X,Y)$ has the same joint law as the given variables.) Therefore
$$E[e^X|Y=1]=e^{1/2} E[e^{tZ}]= e^{1/2} e^{t^2/2}= e^{5/4} \,$$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Moment_and_cumulant_generating_functions

Comment: can you explain the intuition behind $X = \frac{Y}{2} + tZ$ and $t=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$

Comment: The factor $1/2$ in $Y/2$ is just the given correlation. The value of $t$ is determined by the requirement  $1=$Var$(x)=1/4+t^2$.